# Generate JAR files automatically

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a maven project which will generate a JAR file, if you build it as **Maven Install**.
Inside this project, I have a code like this -

```
public class GameBot extends GameController {
public int botNumber = 1
Static String botName = "Bot1";

...// Rest of the code..

}
```

I want to create around 150 JAR files from this project with incremented botNumbers. For example - JAR File 1 should contain botNumber = 1 and botName = Bot1
JAR file 2 should contain botNumber = 2 and BotName = Bot2 .. So on till 150.

I used to build each of these manually and now it looks cumbersome to build each time this way. Because, if I make any small change in the code, I have to build all 150 Files again.

Does any one have some suggestions as in Can I automate the process and get all 150 JAR in a folder built for me?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not sure how to do this exactly, but wouldn't it be helpful to make botName = "Bot" + botNumber so you don't have to change the String each time?

Comment: Where are these files located? All in one package? Are there actually 150 class files. I don't get it

Comment: Sorry for confusion. Here are the steps I follow - 1. Enter the botNumber as 1 in the JAVA file . 2) Right-Click on the project folder and then select RunAs-> Maven Install 3) The previous step will generate a JAR file inside the Project TARGET folder. 4) Copy that JAR file to another folder. 5) Come back to JAVA file and change botNumber = 2 and then repeat the steps..

Comment: Are all these bots required to run in a separate process? Then why not take the bot-number as an argument to your main()-method? Or is it all in a single process? Then make a class with a loop to instanciate 150 bots. No need for 150 jars - that's just madness.

Comment: The bots run in both ways - Separate Process and Individual Process. This depends on the team the bot belongs while playing the game. The BotName and number are important because, The bots will use these values to update it's results to a database. Or else, there would be no way for me to track all these 150 bots when I run them 1500 times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why dont you externalize the botNumber to a property file and using shell script or batch file create the property file and build the maven project.

**Java Code**

```
Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.load(this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/bottest.properties"));
botNumber = Integer.parseInt(properties.getProperty("botnumber"));
botName = "Bot"+botNumber;
```

**Shell Script**

```
#!/bin/sh
mvn clean;
for i in {1..5}
do
    echo "botnumber=$i" > ./src/main/resources/bottest.properties;
    mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip;
    cp target/bottest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar target/bootest$i.jar
done
```

**Batch File**

```
echo off
call mvn clean
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 5) do (
   echo botnumber=%%x > .\src\main\resources\bottest.properties
   call mvn install -Dmaven.test.skip
   copy target\bottest-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar target\bootest%%x.jar
)
```

The above example is for 5 times.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting a possible solution!